# How to apply tiled ground feature to each face of box?

Tags: babylonjs

I want to create a rubik's cube with babylon. I can create tiled ground and manage colors of each face of box. But how to apply a tiled ground feature to the box's face ? Also, I want to access the indices when the user clicks the box faces.

Any solution will be really useful.

Thanks